# Getting MD5 and SHA-1

Tags: ios, objective-c, md5, sha

I am looking for some help in getting MD5 and SHA-1 in my iPhone app.
Can anybody give me an idea on how to get these?

Comment: @user754229: If you Googled for http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS377US377&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+get+md5+and+sha1+in+objective+c+(iPhone) Saurabh's answer would have been the 4th link in results.

Comment: @Paul: SO is trying to consolidate all the information, so that Google will bring people here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87652/discourage-google-for-it-answers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

-(NSString*) sha1:(NSString*)input
{

 NSData *data = [input dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

 uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

 CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

 NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

 for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
 [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

 return output;

}

- (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
{
 const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
 unsigned char digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
 CC_MD5( cStr, (CC_LONG)strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call

 NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

 for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
 [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

 return  output;

}
```

also have a look at my blog post here - 
http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/how-to-get-md5-and-sha1-in-objective-c-ios-sdk/

Comment: Don't forget to add `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>` at the top of your implementation codes. No need to link against `libcommonCrypto.dylib`

Comment: Why do you init the mutableString with CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH*2 and not just do [NSMutableString string] ?

Comment: The line `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];` will break for non-ASCII strings. I suggest using strlen(cstr) instead of input.length.

Comment: Yes, the first two lines of the sha1 method indeed break on unicode characters such as curly quotes.  I fixed this by replacing those two lines with: NSData *data = [input  dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];